# how to Iterate a mongo cursor in a loop in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to iterate through a loop in python but the nested loop is not reaching the incremental element.

Is there any way other than using `range` like "hasNext()"?

```
cursor1 = Collection.find({x : {"$gt" : 1}})
array1 = []
array2 = []
print Collection.count()

for r in range(0, cursor1.count()):
    first = cursor1.next().get("entity")
    array2.append()

    for z in range(len(array2)):
        print len(original_tweets)
        if originalEntity.get("id") != duplicated_entity("id"):
            array2.append(second)
```

Answer (score 22):

Just iterate as you naturally would over cursor objects, I don't see you would want to iterate over it using `range` and `.next()`.

```
cursor1= Collection.find({x : {"$gt" : 1}})
for record in cursor1:
    # do stuff with your record
```

Comment: Ok if the collection has non integer values?? how can I use them in the array??

Comment: @user1511208 the [`for .. in .. ` loop](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) will iterate over all records returned by `cursor1`. You don't need to know the keys in advance (you seem to be assuming this with your attempt to use `range` in the original question).