# How to loop a Documents on a MongoDB Collection and perform a post request with each one?

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb

This is a one time task that I need to perform. I'm new to mongo and programming but I think that I figured out a way of doing it but I need some help with details.

I want to loop over a whole collection and send each document as a POST request.

```
col.find().sort('updatedAt', pymongo.ASCENDING).forEach( javascript function )
```

The above commenad should work. But my concerns are:

1. Instead of js could I use python? I haven't worked with js before.
2. If not, can I create post requests with javascript?
3. Can I do it from the terminal in the mongo shell?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript (ES5)

```
db.collection.find({}).sort('updatedAt': 1).forEach(function(doc){postFunction(doc)});
```

1. You can do this in Python.
2. You can create a post request server-side with Node.js.
3. You cannot send post requests with the mongo shell.

Comment: Thanks. The function inside forEach it's a Javascript right? How can I do it in python? I wouldn't need Node if I do it with python/flask then.

Comment: Yeah, it's a javascript function. To iterate over results one at a time, check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390427/how-to-iterate-a-mongo-cursor-in-a-loop-in-python